# Facebook Authorize doesn't work under IOS 4.01

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, authorization

I'm using `[facebook authorize:permissions]` from the official Facebook IOS API to connect to Facebook using Single Sign On.

My code works fine if the Facebook App is not installed on the device (Safari authorization). It also works fine on a device running IOS5 with the Facebook App installed (Facebook App authorization).

However, on a device running IOS 4.01 (which I keep to test my Apps), if the Facebook App is installed, the `authorize` request launches the Facebook App but when it returns I get the following reply in `application: HandleOpenURL:`

```
fb[MY_APP_ID]://authorize#error=unknown%5Ferror
```

Which causes `fbDidNotLogin:` to be called and my App to fail.

Removing and re-installing the Facebook App and/or my own App does't help. Neither does logging out of Facebook outside my App: The Facebook App presents the Login screen in this case, but then it returns the same error.

If the Facebook App is not installed on that device and Safari is used for authorization, everything works fine.

I read elsewhere that this error may be caused by an incorrect definition of my Bundle ID, but (1) everything is defined correctly in all places (my info.plist, Facebook and iTunes Connect) and (2) things do work in other configurations.

Is there something that is not supported under IOS 4.01 which causes this behavior, or am I doing something wrong? (I'm not doing much actually at this point, I just place an Authorize request and implement the delegate methods).

Answer (score 0):

To correct this behavior you should explicitly disallow facebook authorization with the facebook app. The default code has following line of code -

[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:YES safariAuth:YES];

To disallow authorization with facebook app and force the authorization with safari only, change it to -

[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:NO safariAuth:YES].